# Comparing Values Inside Of Objects With A Constructor Function

Tags: javascript, object

I have created a constructor function in which you can create a card. I am trying to create a method inside this function that checks any of the values or suits of one card object is the same as a different card object. If it is all I just want to send a alert saying the value or suit is the same. 
For example,

card1 = new Card(8, 'clubs')

card2 = new Card(8, 'diamonds')

This would return saying that the value of card 1 and card 2 are the same.

I am not sure how to check each individual Card object and compare it to a another Card object.

```
function Card(value, suit){
this.value = value;
this.suit = suit;
this.check = function(){
    // checking the card objects goes here
}
}

let card1 = new Card(8, 'diamonds');
let card2 = new Card(2, 'clubs');
```

Comment: It's not really clear how you want this to work. Will you pass a card object to `check()` like `someCard.check(someOtherCard)`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I want it to to be able to check all cards in the deck and see if any of the values or suits are matching.

Comment: Ok, so is you deck just an array of card objects? It probably isn't the card's responsibility to keep track of the deck, so maybe you need a deck class — that would be a better place to check if a card is included.

Comment: Why do you need checking function inside the constructor? Instead you could make a separate function which takes two objects and return a boolean based on the OR comparison right?

Comment: @Jake I have corrected the answer according to your requirement can you please check if this is what you desired?

Comment: @RK_15 yes that is better, is there a way to do that if there there isnt a finite ammount of cards. For example, the function is dynamic, it is not only checking card1 and card2 it will be able to check all cards in the deck, wether there is 2 cards or 52 cards.

Comment: @jake Yes you can pass N number of cards using JS spread operator to the check function and then compare them in  a for loop.

Comment: @Jake I have modified the answer according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way that creates a Deck object. You should be able to do this with a plain array as well, but the deck should really be the object that knows what cards are in the deck, which means it should be a function of the deck object.

In general you can just use the array method `some()` and pass it a function that determines true or false:

```js
function Card(value, suit){
  this.value = value;
  this.suit = suit;
}

function Deck(cards){
  this.cards = [...cards]
}

// the function to tell if card value OR suit is in deck
Deck.prototype.includesAny = function(card){
  return this.cards.some(item => item.suit === card.suit || item.value === card.value)
}

let card1 = new Card(8, 'diamonds');
let card2 = new Card(2, 'clubs');
let card3 = new Card(8, 'diamonds')
let card4 = new Card(3, 'hearts')

// a deck with only two cards
let deck = new Deck([card1, card2])

console.log(deck.includesAny(card3)) // deck has both 8 and diamonds
console.log(deck.includesAny(card4)) // no hearts or threes in deck
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the only way i can think -

```
function Card(value, suit, list){
        console.log("ritesh");

        if(check(value, suit, list)){
            this.value = value;
            this.suit = suit;
        } else {            
            console.log("duplicate car found!!");
            return;
        }

        function check(value, suit, list){
            for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (list[i].value === value || list[i].suit === suit) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        this.list = list;
    }
    let list = [];
    list.push(new Card(8, 'diamonds',list));
    list.push(new Card(2, 'clubs',list));
    list.push(new Card(8, 'clubs',list));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
function Card(value, suit){
this.value = value;
this.suit = suit;
this.check = function(...cards){
    for(var card of cards){
      if((this.value == card.value) || (this.suit == card.suit)) return true;
    }     
    return false;
}
}


let card1 = new Card(8, 'diamonds');
console.log(card1.check(new Card(2, 'clubs'), new Card(3,'hearts')));
```

Note:- Here you can pass N number of cards for comparison.

Comment: keyword OR, he's trying to check if the number OR suit is the same, not if the cards are identical.

Comment: Moreover, your check function is not taking any params

Answer (score 0):

Building on previous answer here's a proper way to perform the checking, this also makes sure that the passed object is the same type "Card",
you can also pass an array instead of a single object, and make use of the foreach feature to iterate through the array:

```
function Card(value, suit){
  this.value = value;
  this.suit = suit;
  this.check = function(card2){
    var match = false;
    if(card2 && typeof card2=== 'object' && value.constructor === Card){
      match = ((this.value == card2.value) || (this.suit == card2.suit));
    }
    return match;
  }
}


let card1 = new Card(8, 'diamonds');
let card2 = new Card(2, 'clubs');
console.log(card1.check(card2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Question is a bit unclear but I will assume you will be passing in a card into the function so here is my solution

```
function Card(value, suit){
  this.value = value;
  this.suit = suit;
  this.check = function(cardToCheckAgainst){
    let matchOnSuit = 0;
    let matchOnValue = 0;
    this.suit === cardToCheckAgainst.suit ? matchOnSuite = 1 : matchOnSuite = 0;
    this.value === cardToCheckAgainst.value ? matchOnValue = 1 : matchOnValue = 0;
    if(matchOnSuit == 1){
     alert('both cards have the suit:', this.suit );
    }
    if(matchOnValue == 1){
     alert('both cards have the value:', this.value );
    }
  }
}


let card1 = new Card(8, 'diamonds');
let card2 = new Card(2, 'clubs');
```